# Folder Creation In Windows C#

Tags: c#

I want to create dynamic folder by code in Windows C#.Suppose for each account holder in bank, I have to generate a folder.

Comment: Garima If u found any answer suitable then mark it as answered

Answer (score 1):

very simeple

```
 if(!System.IO.Directory.Exists("Path"))
    {
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("Path");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

[System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s.aspx)

(Assuming it's not in a location that's protected, i.e. needs admin rights (such as Windows Vista/7 restrictions), and your application isn't requiring admin level)

You can also extend the [DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx) class to accept a full path and [recursively create it](http://www.extensionmethod.net/Details.aspx?ID=108)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Directory.CreateDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s.aspx) method:

```
DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\path\to\dir");
if(di.Exists)
   Console.WriteLine("Success!");
```